# Choppy scrolling on mobile (iPhone 6 - Chrome and Safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone

The scrolling on my site: [http:getinjuryanswers.com](http://getinjuryanswers.com) is choppy and stilted on iPhone 6 (Chrome and Safari).  I normally post the code, but in this case I'm not sure what to isolate.

Does anyone know what could be causing that?  Thanks.

Comment: I have generally seen that 'position:fixed' has got some performance issue in iPhone.  Not sure if this is due to that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Correct there is an issue with `position:fixed` (the menu) on iOS also you can have a look at this [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrA85a4ZIaM) by paul lewis. Around 20 mins in he addresses the 4 horsemen of the Jankocalypse which will include issues regarding scrolling.